# Mac OS X Lion Installation Bug

Tags: macos, installation, macbook, osx-lion

I'm trying to install a clean copy of Lion on my Macbook 4,1. So as per instructions, I burned the InstallESD.dmg to a DVD. When booting from the DVD, I get the following message when loading stops:

```
BootCacheControl: Unable to open /var/db/BootCache.playlist: 2 No such file or directory
Bug: launchctl.c:2408 (24957):30: (dbfd = open(g_job_overrides_db_path, O_RDONLY | O_EXLOCK | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)) != -1
```

About a minute later I get a kernel panic. This has happened everytime I have tried to boot it from the DVD. Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: Faulty DVD? To check to see if it didn't burn correctly do a checksum on the DVD and image.

Comment: @Dean The checksums are correct. I was reading more on this error and people suggested some kernel extensions that I didn't understand. Any idea?